# JWT athorization on api through a 3rd server

Tags: laravel, api, jwt, lumen

Okay let's explain the situation.

I have 3 servers that are connected with eachother.

**1 server - The JWT Authorization** - Has Laravel

Everyone that registers and login to this server. So it's a central point. On login you get a token and redirected back to the gateway server.

**2 server - Somthing like a gateway for server 3** - Has Laravel

You can do all kinds of things on this server. Like posting a task

**3 server - Api for the tasks** - Has Lumen

On this server all the tasks are stored with the user `id`so it can be retrieved in the future.

I've gotten a JWT token from the central server and I can authorize with this token on the gateway, but if you post a task to the api server.
How can I access the id from the user or even check if he is authorized to do this action?

I've thought about it and came up with this

Do you give the JWT token as a header along with the task to the api server, then checks this token against the JWT server and return the user credentials so you can use the `id` to retrieve the task in the future. If yes, what is the best aproach for this? Maybe somthing like guzzle?

or

Use a shared secret to decode the JWT and get the user `id` from it.

Comment: yes the best way to check if a user is authenticated is to use guzzle, you set the token in the header and make request

Comment: Do your auth and api servers share a networked filesystem?